# Shiny : dynamic form/ui : last observer in a list does not trigger removeUI

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I am trying to build a dynamic form where the user can add some criteria (via an actionButton) and select values for those criteria. When he's done selecting he may launch some computation.
Every criterion may be removed via a 'delete' button.

It works quite fine for all except the last inserted component that does not react to the related remove button.
The last component is removed only when the "Add criteria" button is clicked.

Is it a bug or could you point my mistake ?

I'm using an observeEvent with a renderUI to build components:

In server.R

```
observeEvent(input$go, {

output$ui <- renderUI({

    rows <- lapply(names(components),buildComponent)

    res = do.call(fluidRow, rows)

})

makeObservers()

})
```

makeObservers creates an observeEvent closure for every component :

```
makeObservers <- eventReactive(input$go, {

IDs <- names(components) 

new_ind <- !(IDs %in% vals$y)    

res <- lapply(IDs[new_ind], function (x) {

  observeEvent(input[[paste0("rmv", x)]], {

    if(components[[x]] == "Main1") removeComponent(x)
  })
})
} , 
 ignoreNULL = F, ignoreInit = F)
```

Please find a working example.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

criterias <- c("Criteria 1", "Criteria 2", "Criteria 3", "Criteria 4")
components <<- list()
counter <<- 0

buildComponent <- function(val) {
  idselect = paste0("select", val)
  idremove <- paste0("rmv", val)
  div(
    selectInput(idselect, "criteria :", criterias, criterias[0]),
    actionButton(idremove, paste0("X", val),icon = icon("remove"), size = "small")
  )
}

removeComponent <- function(x) {
  print(paste0("Removing" ,x))
  xpath1 = paste0("div:has(> #select", x ,")" )
  xpath2 = paste0("div:has(> #rmv", x ,")" )
  removeUI(
    selector = xpath1, multiple = T#, immediate=T
  )
  removeUI(
    selector = xpath2, multiple = T#, immediate=T
  )
  components[[as.character(x)]] <<- NULL
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      actionButton("go", "Criteria", icon = icon("plus-circle"), 
                                   size = "small"),
                      uiOutput("ui")
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      actionButton("activate", "show cpts"),
                      textOutput('show_components')
                    )
) )

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Keep track of which observer has been already created
  vals <- reactiveValues(y = NULL)

  makeObservers <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    IDs <- names(components) 
    new_ind <- !(IDs %in% vals$y)
    print("new_ind")
    print(IDs[new_ind])
    # update reactive values
    vals$y <- names(components) 
    res <- lapply(IDs[new_ind], function (x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("rmv", x)]], {
    print(paste0("rmv", x))
    print(components[[x]])
    if(components[[x]] == "Main1") removeComponent(x)
      })
    })
  } , ignoreNULL = F, ignoreInit = F)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      print(counter)
      counter <<- counter + 1
    components[[as.character(counter)]] <<- "Main1"
    print("adding component : ")
    print(paste0(names(components),collapse = ";"))
    rows <- lapply(names(components),buildComponent)
    res = do.call(fluidRow, rows)
    })
    makeObservers()
  })

  observeEvent(input$activate, {
    output$show_components <- renderPrint({
      components
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks to great remarks from  Mike Wise, i ve been able to spot the precise problem: (see comment in Mike answer). Here is some code :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

criterias <- c("Criteria 1", "Criteria 2", "Criteria 3", "Criteria 4")
components <<- list()
counter <<- 0

buildComponent <- function(val) {
  idselect = paste0("select", val)
  idremove <- paste0("rmv", val)
  div(
    selectInput(idselect, "criteria :", criterias, criterias[0]),
    actionButton(idremove, paste0("X", val),icon = icon("remove"), size = "small")
  )
}

removeComponent <- function(x) {
  print(paste0("Removing" ,x))
  xpath1 = paste0("div:has(> #select", x ,")" )
  xpath2 = paste0("div:has(> #rmv", x ,")" )
  removeUI(
    selector = xpath1, multiple = T#, immediate=T
  )
  removeUI(
    selector = xpath2, multiple = T#, immediate=T
  )
  components[[as.character(x)]] <<- NULL
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("go", "Criteria", icon = icon("plus-circle"), 
             size = "small"),
    uiOutput("ui")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("activate", "show cpts"),
    textOutput('show_components')
  )
) )

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Keep track of which observer has been already created
  vals <- reactiveValues(y = NULL)

  makeObservers <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    IDs <- names(components) 
    new_ind <- !(IDs %in% vals$y)
    print("new_ind")
    print(IDs[new_ind])
    # update reactive values
    vals$y <- names(components) 
    res <- lapply(IDs[new_ind], function (x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("rmv", x)]], {
    print(paste0("rmv", x))
    print(components[[x]])
    if(components[[x]] == "Main1") removeComponent(x)
      })
    })
  } , ignoreNULL = F, ignoreInit = F)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    counter <<- counter + 1
    components[[as.character(counter)]] <<- "Main1"
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      print(counter)
      print("adding component : ")
      print(paste0(names(components),collapse = ";"))
      rows <- lapply(names(components),buildComponent)
      res = do.call(fluidRow, rows)
    })
    makeObservers()
  })

  observeEvent(input$activate, {
    output$show_components <- renderPrint({
      components
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there were some problems in the code, and I had to make some small but important changes to understand it, and then get it to work as intended. However it is essentially the same code.

Changes:

- Changed `rv$y` to `rv$prev_components`.
- Put your `components` and `counter` variable into the `reactiveValues` to get rid of the `<<-`, seeing as you were using `reactiveValues` already which obviates the need for `<<-`
- Added a `setdiff` to find the new addition to your names (this was key).
- Changed `makeObervables` into a simple function (it was not being used as an `eventReactive` at all anyway).
- Probably a few other small things that are forgotten.

This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

criterias <- c("Criteria 1", "Criteria 2", "Criteria 3", "Criteria 4")

vals <- reactiveValues(prev_components=list(),components=list(),counter=0)

buildComponent <- function(val) {
  idselect = paste0("select", val)
  idremove <- paste0("rmv", val)
  div(
    selectInput(idselect, "criteria :", criterias, criterias[0]),
    actionButton(idremove, paste0("X", val),icon = icon("remove"), size = "small")
  )
}

removeComponent <- function(x) {
  print(paste0("Removing" ,x))
  xpath1 = paste0("div:has(> #select", x ,")" )
  xpath2 = paste0("div:has(> #rmv", x ,")" )
  removeUI(
    selector = xpath1, multiple = T#, immediate=T
  )
  removeUI(
    selector = xpath2, multiple = T#, immediate=T
  )
  vals$components[[as.character(x)]] <<- NULL
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("go", "Criteria", icon = icon("plus-circle"),
                 size = "small"),
    uiOutput("uii")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("activate", "show cpts"),
    textOutput('show_components')
  )
) )


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  makeObservers <- function() {
    IDs <- names(vals$components)
    new_ind <- setdiff(IDs,vals$prev_components)

    vals$prev_components <- names(vals$components)
    res <- lapply(new_ind, function (x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("rmv", x)]], {
        print(paste0("rmv", x))
        print(vals$components[[x]])
        if(vals$components[[x]] == "Main1") removeComponent(x)
      })
    })
  }

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    print(vals$counter)
    vals$counter <- vals$counter + 1
    vals$components[[as.character(vals$counter)]] <- "Main1"

    output$uii <- renderUI({
      print("adding component : ")
      print(paste0(names(vals$components),collapse = ";"))
      rows <- lapply(names(vals$components),buildComponent)
      res = do.call(fluidRow, rows)
    })
    makeObservers()
  })

  observeEvent(input$activate, {
    output$show_components <- renderPrint({
      vals$components
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and improvements.

Comment: Precise problem comes from updating global variables in renderUI : counter <<- counter + 1 and    components[[as.character(counter)]] <<- "Main1". When they re in the upper level (observeEvent)  non elegant code at least works.  See working code at the end of my question

Comment: Still use of <<- is discouraged and can usually be avoided by using reactive values. And glad I could help out.